# Set activity to specific orientation before it start

Tags: android

Is there a way  I can start activity in a specific orientation (programmatically) without having it to be recreated again? Right now if I call setRequestedOrientation  from the the OnCreate and the orientation is different than the current then the activity is destoryed and restarted again.

Thank you

Comment: got any solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

For me solution was to lock orientation of Activity

**android:screenOrientation="locked"**

, and now it depends only on setRequestedOrientation():

```
   <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="locked">
```

No restarting anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your orientation in Manifest file

```
       <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted it programmatically not through xml

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't want activity to restart, add configChanges for the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="com.myexample.SplashScreen"
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
   ```

   and then call setRequestedOrientation to set orientation programtically.
2. But if you want to lock the activity to 1 orientation. It is good to set it in Manifest by adding android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: whats the down side for not having the activity restart?

Comment: refer configChanges here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called. You have handle the layout configuration changes for landscape and portrait in onConfigurationChanged().